# More than one true in same tensor fiber

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Given the array `a_ij` with shape `(n,m)` whose column's sum to one:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

**Without for loops**, I would like to find the 1-d `np.ndarray` `b_j` with shape `(m,)`, whose `j`'th element contains `True` if there is at least one other `True` value in the same `i`'th row that already has the `j`'th column's `True` value in it.  (Wow that was a mouthful, and not even that clear...).

The answer would be:

```
>>> b
array([1,1,0])
```

Reading `b`: a `True` value in the first element means, there was at least one other `True` value in the first row of `a` (i.e. second column).  The third element of `b` being `False` signals that there was no other `True` value in the second row of array `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand everything right:

```
(a.sum(axis=1) > 1) @ a
```